# Oracle 11g XMLType object relational Storage -> XML Schema validation

Tags: oracle, validation, schema, oracle11g, xmltype

i got the following problem. Each time I try to load an XML File via JDBC in my Oracle DB I get an ORA-19007 Error: schema of document doesn´t match with schema http://myServerURL/mondial.xsd

In Oxygen however I validated the mondial.xml and mondial.xsd, so I got no clue what Oracle´s problem is with the files.

My XML

```
<mondial  xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myServerURL/mondial.xsd">
```

My Schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

And the registering was successful

```
BEGIN DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
                   SCHEMAURL  => 'http://myServerURL/mondial.xsd'
                   SCHEMADOC  => HTTPURIType('http://myServerURL/mondial.xsd').getClob()
                   LOCAL      => false,     -- local
                   GENTYPES   => false,     -- generate object types
                   GENBEAN    => false,     -- no java beans
                   GENTABLES  => false,     -- generate object tables
                   FORCE      => true
                   OWNER      => USER)
                   END;
```

The Table Create query

```
create Table MYTABLE (id Number, mondial XMLTYPE) XMLTYPE Column mondial
                          XMLSCHEMA "http://myServerURL/mondial.xsd"
                              ELEMENT "mondial";
```

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: could you share your mondial.xml/xsd files ?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the attempt to insert data into the XMLTYPE column, I assume you are creating the XMLType object from the text source. When you do this, are you including the namespace schemas in the schema argument to the XMLType function? A change in 11g is that namespaces are verified against their schema just upon creation of the XMLType object, and these must be specified.